# Javascript email validation regex inclusion

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax-error

I got the javascript email validation code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript). According to the all the answers the RFC2822 regex is as per following:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

I tried to include this in js, but it gives a syntax error.

```
var email = this.value;
if(email.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/) )
{
    //matched...
} else {
    //not matched..
}
```

I am using eclipse, and it's giving the error as soon as I enter this code. Here are some of the errors from the long list

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on tokens, ArrayLiteralHeader expected instead
- Syntax error on token "?", invalid Expression
- Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token
- Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Arguments
- Missing semicolon
- Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete PrimaryNoNewArray
- Syntax error on tokens, ArrayLiteralHeader expected instead
- Syntax error on token "^", invalid (
```

Please let me know how to properly include email validation regex into the code?

#### EDIT

Tried in browser console. Exact same syntax works in chrome js console. Here is the output

[image: Web console]

Thanks

Comment: Apparently `/` don't close the literal when it is inside a character class, but Eclipse might not understand this. Escape all `/` inside the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript regex literal need `/` to enclose it.

```
if(email.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/) )
{
    //matched...
} else {
    //not matched..
}
```

Comment: Please, check the same thing in eclipse if you can. I can't get what's wrong? Same error as posted in the questions.

Comment: @mtk Just try it in the browser console.

Comment: @xdazz: yeah, I just noticed that, sorry. But this could still be the reason for the error in Eclipse.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, that may be the reason ~

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you use regexes like the below:

```
myString.match(/<regexHere>/)
```

Comment: I have no experience with eclipse. I am guessing it has some bug with (basic) Javascript grammar. Could you try executing it directly?

Answer (score 0):

the regex must be encapsulated by "/" in javascript:

```
    if (/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i.test(subject)) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    }
```

Comment: Please, check the same thing in eclipse if you can. I can't get what's wrong? Same error as posted in the questions.

Comment: eclipse?
are you *sure* that you're doing JavaSCRIPT?

Comment: yes, I am doing a php project with some css, js, and obviously html.